# Can I generate a new PayPal Identity Token?

Tags: paypal

I can't find out where to generate a new identity token for PayPal, is this possible?

The token is visible under My Account > Profile > My Selling Preferences > Website Preferences.

Answer (score 1):

By 'new', do you mean you already have an existing one, and you want to have it changed?
No, this is not possible.